# How does the new layout used in Fujifilm X-Pro1 sensor improve image quality?

Tags: fujifilm-xpro1, anti-aliasing, bayer

One of the allegedly big advantages of Fujifilm X-Pro1 is its new color filter array layout, which does not require anti-aliasing filter in front of it. In theory, this could mean notable improvement in perceived sharpness and details. Also, Moirè effect should be avoided with the reduced repetitiveness in filter pattern.

Are there any image comparisons available taken with the X-Pro vs a conventional Bayer sensor DSLR with similar specs (APS-C around 16MP), showing how these advantages work out in reality?

Comment: A link to the sensor's description (image?) may be helpful...

Comment: The Intertubes are bursting with X-Pro1 samples right now, a great resource is this aggregator here: http://www.scoop.it/t/fuji-x-pro1 While this is a quirky camera (like the X100 is), pretty much all the reviews I've read are unequivocal about the IQ, and the sharpness of the photos with the f/1.4 50mm (equiv). I do have the X-Pro1 and the f/1.4 50mm (equiv) and it can easily compete with my 5DMII equipped with the Canon 50 f/1.4 in IQ, even up to high ISOs. I started a side by side comparison of the 5DMIII vs X-Pro1, shooting the same scene, but I'm not quite done with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In contrast to the standard 2x2 bayer pattern the X-Pro 1's sensor uses a 6x6 pattern ([see this link for images](http://www.dpreview.com/previews/fujifilmxpro1/3))

```
R,G,R,G,R,G        G,B,G,G,R,G
G,B,G,B,G,B        R,G,R,B,G,B
R,G,R,G,R,G        G,B,G,G,R,G
G,B,G,B,G,B        G,R,G,G,B,G
R,G,R,G,R,G        B,G,B,R,G,R
G,B,G,B,G,B        G,R,G,G,B,G
```

The new pattern results in every horizontal and vertical line being covered by all three photosite colours, the lack of which is the main source of moire in bayer pattern sensors. They combat this by using an anti-aliasing filter to (slightly) blur the image to ensure that all lines will hit all three colours. The lack of this blurring in the image that hits the X-Pro 1's sensor results in the potential for increased sharpness and image quality, which seems to be born out in reviews, see [here](http://www.luminous-landscape.com/reviews/cameras/fuji_x_pro1_review.shtml) and [here](http://www.stevehuffphoto.com/2012/04/04/the-fuji-x-pro-1-digital-camera-review-by-steve-huff/)

dpreview allows you to compare the X-Pro 1 to a wide range of cameras (shooting the same test scene) [here](http://www.dpreview.com/previews/fujifilmxpro1/6).

Comment: You've explained the differences, but does it improve image quality? And if so, how / why?

Comment: He did explain it, you know... The Fuji has a A) irregular RGB pixel layout, which means  that B) it doesn't need to have an antialiasing filter to fix the moiré that a regular RGB layout suffers from which means that C) the sensor does not see the slightly blurred image that the antialias filter produces which means D) sharper pictures.